# UITableView section header floating after changing tab

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` as one of my tabs (`UITabBarController`). 
After switch to another tab and then going back to ma UITableViewController, the section header is floating in the middle of the screen.

Also, a small scrolling is enough to replace it at its right position.

Has anyone has this kind of problem and any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Sounds like a layout issue. Can you paste a screenshot so that we understand you better?

Comment: Yes it's somehow a layout issue but I see nothing in my code that would trigger this kind of behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `setNeedsLayout()` on my tableview in `viewDidLoad()` solved the probleM.